# Assign random numbers in a grid with no duplicates in Python

Tags: python, random, duplicates

I have 16 variables arranged in a 4 by 4 grid.
My goal is to make a function that can assigns a random number between 0 and 4 to every variables, with no duplicates in each column and each row - like a sudoku.

Each method I've tried results in duplicates. For example:

```
column_A = [A1, A2, A3, A4]
column_B = [B1, B2, B3, B4]
column_C = [C1, C2, C3, C4]
column_D = [D1, D2, D3, D4]
row_1 = [A1, B1, C1, D1]
row_2 = [A2, B2, C2, D2]
row_3 = [A3, B3, C3, D3]
row_4 = [A4, B4, C4, D4]
all_rows = [row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4]
all_columns = [column_A, column_B, column_C, column_D]


def random_grid():
    for i in range(len(all_rows)):
      all_columns[i] = sample([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 4)
      all_rows[i] = sample([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 4)
```

doesn't work
How could I do this?

Comment: I am happy to write you few different solution, but show my working code that indeed creates random 4x4 grid (even with duplicates)

Comment: I'd travel through the matrix in reading order (left to right, up to down) and fill each cell with a number randomly chosen from a list of available numbers ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 minus the ones already used to the left of your cell and above your cell).

Comment: Well indeed, this method can fail, which my code just proved to me :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create a "baseline" grid, where no two rows or columns are the same. For example, for a grid of size 4x4, the baseline would be:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [4, 1, 2, 3],
 [3, 4, 1, 2],
 [2, 3, 4, 1]]
```

Then shuffle the rows, then shuffle the columns.

Pure python:

`random.shuffle` only shuffles the elements of the list you passed. In order to shuffle columns, you will need to transpose the list-of-lists such that the first axis groups *columns* instead of rows.

```
import random

def random_grid(size=4):
    r = list(range(1, size+1))
    baseline = [r[-n:] + r[:-n] for n in range(size)]
    random.shuffle(baseline)
    transpose = [list(col) for col in zip(*baseline)]
    random.shuffle(transpose)
    return transpose
```

Using numpy:

`np.random.shuffle` only shuffles the first axis, so we transpose the array before shuffling it another time.

```
import numpy as np

def random_grid(size=4):
    r = list(range(1, size+1))
    baseline = np.array([r[-n:] + r[:-n] for n in range(size)])
    np.random.shuffle(baseline)
    np.random.shuffle(baseline.T)
    return baseline
```

---

Now, since you want random numbers between *0* and `size`, you can just get a grid that is one row and column larger than what you want, subtract one from every element, and discard the extra row and column.

Pure python:

```
def random_grid_2(size=4):
    rgrid = random_grid(size+1)
    return [[i - 1 for i in row[:-1]] for row in grid[:-1]]
```

Numpy:

```
def random_grid_2(size=4):
    rgrid = random_grid(size+1) - 1
    return rgrid[:-1, :-1]
```

Of course, this approach is less efficient than doing it in `random_grid` in the first place, when you are creating the grid, but I have kept the two steps separate to help you understand what is happening.

Comment: This works nicely, but only uses numbers 1-4 and not 0-4, so it only provides a subset of all possible matrices.

Comment: @Swifty that's a good point that I totally overlooked. I've added a fix for that now.

Comment: Nice trick for your fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's some code that implements my method; more for demonstration than for practical use since, as was said in a comment, it can fail (if there are no choice left, which can happen for the 3 numbers in the bottom right corner of the matrix); this could be addressed by catching the error and restarting the process, but it's not very elegant.

```
from random import choice

numbers = {0,1,2,3,4}

a=[[],[],[],[]]

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        available = list(numbers - set(a[i][:j]) - {a[x][j] for x in range(i)})
        a[i].append(choice(available))
        
print(a)
```

Here's the amended code (with error catching); it will always work, but at the cost of potentially creating several failed matrices before a working one.

```
from random import choice

numbers = {0,1,2,3,4}

failed = True
while failed:
    a=[[],[],[],[]]
    failed = False
    try:
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                available = list(numbers - set(a[i][:j]) - {a[x][j] for x in range(i)})
                a[i].append(choice(available))
    except:
        failed = True
        
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pranav showed one great solution. A naive one (which should work in that case) could be generate any matrix and check if it's correct one.

Simple implementation:

```
from random import sample

def check(matrix, size=4):
    return check_rows(matrix, size) and check_cols(matrix, size)

def check_rows(matrix, size=4):
    return all(len(set(matrix[i])) == size for i in range(size))

def check_cols(matrix, size=4):
    transposed = [[matrix[j][i] for j in range(size)] for i in range(size)]
    return check_rows(transposed, size)

def generate(size=4):
    return [sample(range(5), size) for _ in range(size)]

while True:
    matrix = generate()
    if check(matrix):
        break

print(matrix)
```